# PHP pass variable to LESS CSS or identify current environment in LESS

Tags: php, css, less

In my LESS CSS file I define a base-url:

```
@base-url: 'http://cdn.domain.com';
```

I now have the need to dynamically switch the base url depending on what environment I am on. Ex:

```
DEV: 'http://domain.com'
PROD: 'http://cdn.domain.com'
```

Is there a way to check this directly via LESS or is there a way to pass this variable from PHP to LESS?

Comment: You should be compiling and minifying your LESS files for production in the same way that you'd use a different `.ini` file for production.

Comment: I suppose I could just do a simple find/replace in PHP on deployment to set the correct environmental base URL..

Comment: That's not at all what I mean. When you set up your project for different environments, you'd want to have different `.ini` files for each environment. For compiling less, you'll want to set up a different `variables.less` file for each environment, so that you can run a build in each different environment and get the appropriate output for each one.

Comment: Oh i see, I never thought of that. I'll give that a look. I'm very new to LESS and project integration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create two files, one for development, one for production, and compile whichever you need:

```css
/* Production: production.less */
@base-url: 'http://cdn.domain.com';
@import "main.less"

/* Development: dev.less */
@base-url: 'http://dev.domain.com/files';
@import "main.less";
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm going to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to parse php variable to less files.

http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using lessphp

Comment: So why not use ? if you want to send a php variable for less that is the way to do it

Comment: I don't want to integrate a different compiler just for that feature. @zzzzBov's method looks way better in my situation.